# GROK Pattern Works with GROK Debugger but not in Logstash GROK

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a GROK pattern  I am trying to use in Logstash that works within the GROK Debugger [website](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com) but not within Log stash. I've tried different configurations with no success. I'm hoping someone can help me identify why this is not working.

**Input**:  2015-04-15 12:43:23.788 1883 AUDIT nova.compute.resource_tracker [-] Free disk (GB): -7

**Search Pattern**: Free disk \(GB\): \-%{INT:auth_method}

I want to extract  the value ***7***

Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: This worked fine for me. Please provide your Logstash configuration. (Side note: You probably want `%{INT:auth_method:int}` to make the auth_method field an integer field instead of a string field.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say it, OP, but it works for me:

```
input {
        stdin {}
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => [ message, "Free disk \(GB\): \-%{INT:auth_method}" ]
    }
}
output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Gives you this:

```
2015-04-15 12:43:23.788 1883 AUDIT nova.compute.resource_tracker [-] Free disk (GB): -7
{
        "message" => "2015-04-15 12:43:23.788 1883 AUDIT nova.compute.resource_tracker [-] Free disk (GB): -7",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2015-04-16T15:57:17.229Z",
           "host" => "0.0.0.0",
    "auth_method" => "7"
}
```

Check for extra spaces at the end of your pattern, perhaps?